# Adding numbers in a object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var numbers = [{grades:[100,100,100]}];
var result = 0;

for (var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    for (var p in numbers.grades[i]);

    result+=p+":"+numbers[i][p];
    //console.log(p+":"+numbers[i][p])
    console.log(result);
}
```

this is what i have so far. I know how to get all the numbers in the .grades but i want them all added up in a very simple way.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is `numbers.length` is only `1`. You want

```
numbers[0].grades.length; // 3
```

This should sum the grades for you

```
for (var i=0, sum=0; i<numbers[0].grades.length; i++) {
  sum += numbers[0].grades[i];
}

sum; // 300
```

---

If you have access to [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), you could use this

```
var sum = numbers[0].grades.reduce(function(a, b) { return a +  b; }, 0);

sum; // 300
```

**Note** `.reduce` requires ECMAScript `>= 5` and will not work in `IE <= 8`

Comment: Great solution!  In this scenario it is safe to assume numbers[0], but we should wrap the reduce in a numbers.forEach function to enable any future development.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it

```
var numbers = [{grades:[100,100,100]}];
var result = 0;

for (var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    for (var g=0; g<numbers[i].grades.length; g++) {

    result = result+numbers[i].grades[g];
    console.log(result);
    }
}
```

As discussed, if it does support ES5, you can write it like this:

```
var numbers = [{grades:[100,100,100]}];
var result = 0;

numbers.forEach( function(val) {
    result = result + val.grades.reduce( function (previousValue, currentValue, index, array) {
        return previousValue + currentValue;
    })
});
```

**just remember that you need to loop through the numbers array, instead of giving it a default value of '0' // numbers[0]grades etc**

Answer (score 0):

or you can try:

```
for(var j=0; j<numbers.length;j++)
{
  for (var i=0, sum=0; i<numbers[j].grades.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[j].grades[i];
  }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

The list you want to loop through is :

```
var list = numbers[0].grades;
```

Then, inside the loop :

```
result += list[i];
```

That's it :)

---

How to browse a javascript array :

```
var a = ['I', 'need', 'the', 'basics'];
console.log(a[0]); // "I"
console.log(a[3]); // "basics"
console.log(a[a.length - 1]); // "basics"
```

How to browse a javascript object :

```
var o = { a: 'I', b: 'need', c: 'the', d: 'basics' };
console.log(o.a); // "I"
console.log(o.d); // "basics"
console.log(o['d']); // "basics"
```

All together :

```
var mixed = [{ a: 'foo' }, { b: 'bar' }, { c: ['baz'] }];
console.log(mixed[0].a); // "foo"
console.log(mixed[1].b); // "bar"
console.log(mixed[2].c[0]); // "baz"
```

---

To add up all grades :

```
var grades, i, j;
var sum = 0;
var list = [
    { grades: [1, 2, 3] },
    { grades: [4, 5, 6] }
];

for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    grades = list[i].grades;
    for (j = 0; j < grades.length; j++) {
        sum += grades[j];
    }
}

console.log(sum); // 21
```

Comment: @user3079589 Great :D But you should rather express your enthusiasm by voting or by accepting your favorite answer : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235. Keep enjoying :D

Answer (score 0):

A more functional/javascript approach would be to use [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var sum = numbers[0].grades.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
    return previousValue + currentValue;
});

console.log(sum);
```